# Strange Error in Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-indigo

Has anyone ever seen this kinf of error in Eclipse Indigo?

```
An internal error occurred during: "Label Job".
Illegal class name "com/sun+jdi/DoubleType" in class file com/sun/jdi/DoubleType
```

[image]

**Version: Indigo Service Release 1**

**Build id: 20110916-0149**

I've added a new Schreenshot.
Labebl Job is shown when i click on next step (F6, F8..)
JDI thread evaluation is shown when i drag the mouse on a variable for have informations.

[image]

I've never seen this strange error.

Comment: There is a bug similar to this. Check https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=247274

Comment: When i'm debugging my android App. More precisely when i call a RestClient with a specific request. If i run the application normally it shows a JSON parsing error, but in debug mode it shows the above error.

Comment: @AdelBoutros, Yes it's similar, but is not a Null Pointer Exception my error

Comment: Every Step (when i click F6 o F8 or any other button) the error is shown... :-(

Comment: You can try the solution proposed

Comment: Try reinstalling eclipse

Comment: yes, It's the best solution everytime.

Comment: Before you are reinstalling eclipse, try to create fresh workspace. Maybe this will help.

Comment: @Aerox Just curious, what OS are you running Eclipse on?

Comment: That was Windows 7 Professional (I don't remember if it was 32 bit or 64bit with PAE extension, much more probable the latter). I'm talking in a past tense because I've changed the laptop (that was an Asus PRO31S) into a MacBookPro Late 2013. I don't remember how exactly I managed that, but for sure i tried all the suggestions, and the only one that works was reinstalling eclipse. We're talking about 3 years ago, so I've not everything clear in my mind. Sorry ;-)

Comment: @Aerox if you find the right solution in any of these comments, please don't forget to mention it in your question or just answer yourself and mark it as solved ;D

Comment: If reinstalling Eclipse would be a solution, ok I will mark it as best answer even if it's me to reply at this question. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since someone asked me to set an answer in order to mark this question as solved even if someone will probably still have this problem unsolved, but as you can see nobody solved it in different ways (since for the majority there are at least two solutions for problems), so i would mark this answer as best answer:

**[My Solution] Delete your Eclipse "installation" and reinstall it to be clean from every errors. Re-install it until the problem is gone (and so there are no installation errors)**

If someone is opposed to this answer as best answer, please write it down a real best answer, or make yourself agree with @Drumnbass (that "suggested" me to write the answer) to understand what is right and what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I just faced the same issue. I was able to solve the issue by removing all the breakpoints by clicking the double cross button and then restarting the eclipse.

[image]